# How to store the ajax response in browser cache with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, browser-cache

I'm trying to store the ajax response in browser cache. I know to store it for only url like (example.com), but want to store the data which having url like (`example.com?xyz=abc%20efg&mno=hjk`).

My code :

```
beforeSend: function () {
                var addC=url;          // I want to add data also with this url
                console.log(addC);
                if (localCache.exist(addC)) {
                    printRes(localCache.get(url));
                    console.log("cached values");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            },
```

And

```
var localCache = {
    data: {},
    remove: function (url) {
        delete localCache.data[url];
    },
    exist: function (url) {
        return localCache.data.hasOwnProperty(url) && localCache.data[url] !== null;
    },
    get: function (url) {
        console.log('Getting in cache for url' + url);
        return localCache.data[url];
    },
    set: function (url, cachedData, callback) {
        localCache.remove(url);
        localCache.data[url] = cachedData;
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) callback(cachedData);
    }
};
```

Please anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: What are asking here? Each url is just a key to a value in your map object, with or without parameters. Are you asking how to convert an object to a URL encoded string? If so, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557087/library-to-convert-json-to-urlencoded). Still not sure this will work properly as you need to make sure the url parameters are always in the right order...

Answer (score 0):

By reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) from 
MDN i Think you are doing wrong. If you want to cache ajax response `CACHE` property to `true`
in your ajax call ,also see to it that you provide proper cache expiration header from server.
Also 
[from MDN]

Never access cached files by using traditional GET parameters (like other-cached-
    page.html?parameterName=value). This will make the browser bypass the cache and attempt to get
     it from network. To link to cached resources that have parameters parsed in JavaScript use 
    parameters in the hash part of the link, such as other-cached-page.html#whatever?parameterName=value.

if you are looking for local storage[key value storage]

```
globalStorage['cache_1'].setItem("key",data);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. What I want to do is when user requests for some data ajax will sends the request to the server, When data received from the server first time it must store in the browser cache. when user asks for same data next time that will be shown from the cache. My code works when I use url `/example`. But my problem is I have different requests for same url at that point it will show the cached data for different request. So that reason I want to use `ajax data:` also with the `url:`.